# Excel Interop Screen Updates Slow, Defer screen

Tags: c#, excel, performance, interop, refresh

I have written an AddIn Toolbar for Excel using Interop.  It affects spreadsheets by adding rows, adding columns, formatting rows, across multiple sheets, entering formulas and values into cells, etc.
The problem is that Excel wants to show all these on the screen which is very slow.  Can I make them invisible until the process is complete?  It looks like setting sheets or ranges as Active forces them to become visible
Am I correct?
What can I do? (Originally had this problem in VS2010 and still have it in VS2015.
Thanks!  Harvey

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the start of the macro: `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`

Then add this to the end `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` and `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic`.